# connection string is not recognized after change to web.config, and code files

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, connection-string

**Problem:** When I run my C#.net 3.5 web app on local machine (Win 7 64 bit)  using VS 2008, and after changing connection string in code and in web.config file* to an alternate *test* database on same SQL server, the app continues to point to the former production database instead of the latter *test*database.

I have changed the connection string everywhere they are defined - 8 class files, and in web.config.  The code I’m testing only uses 2 of the 8 files. My connection string (in all 8 files) looks like this:

```
this.cnConn.ConnectionString = "workstation id=XXNNNN;packet size=4096;integrated security=SSPI;data source=SERVERNAME;persist security info=False;initial catalog=test"; //USE FOR DEVELOPMENT
```

Could there be a “master” connection string in another config file somewhere?  On IIS? How do I get my code to recognize my code changes?  Is this a debugging issue? I have been working on this for 2 days with no success.

Comment: make sure that the security / port / and other things of that nature are the same on the target server.. don't assume because the connection string in the config works in `Dev` that it will work also in `IST` or `Prod` environments. also that's one heck of an odd connection string what type of database are you connecting to..? there is a site on google that has lots of connection string examples based on the type of DB Server you have http://www.dofactory.com/Connect/Connect.aspx

Comment: If you have seach and replace all connection string in your code, try to give a IIS reset.

Comment: I'm connecting to SQL Server 2008. The app was formerly v7.1 which I converted to v9.0. I added the connection string to Connection string in local IIS and reset IIS.  No change.I found this in web.config file - could it have anything to do with the problem?:<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=nnn.0.0.1:nnnnn" sqlConnectionString="data source=nnn.0.0.n;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />